# How to Get Specific text from string address using regular expression?

Tags: javascript, regex, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have been trying to extract the 'XYZ Name' from this address:

```
*Address: *

XYZ Name
X Address
Y Address
Z Address
```

if we have an address like this:

```
Address:
XYZ Name
X Address
Y Address
Z Address
```

then we can use the following regular expression to get Address and XYZ Name:

```
var myRegex1 = /Address\s*.*/mi;
var bracket2 = myRegex2.exec(msgBody);
```

But due to the changed format of Address to *Address: *, this regular expression doesn't work anymore. Any suggestion would be much appreciated.

Comment: Get contents from group 1: [`^\*?Address:\s*\*?\s*(.+)`](https://regex101.com/r/7O8GGW/1) [code](https://regex101.com/r/7O8GGW/1/codegen?language=javascript)

Comment: Or `^(?:\*Address: \*|Address:)\s*(.+)` https://regex101.com/r/gtcgob/1

Comment: if we use this as:
`var myRegex2 = /^(?:\*Address: \*|Address:)\s*(.+)/;
var bracket2 = myRegex2.exec(msgBody);`

then it gives null value.

Comment: @Roomi See https://jsfiddle.net/e04dcxgo/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So from the regular expression provided by @Gurmanjot Singh, I was able to extract the required text mentioned in the question. So following snippet can be used for that:

```
var myRegex2 = / *\*?Address\s*\*?\s*(.+)/g;
var bracket2 = myRegex2.exec(msgBody); 
Logger.log(bracket2[bracket2.length-1]);
```

Comment: I think this was Gurmanjot's. But regardless, if it works, then that's good.